# Netbeans Less CSS (Node.js preprocessor) not recognizing Mixin

Tags: node.js, windows, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans, less

**Environment**

- Netbeans IDE 8.0
- Windows 7
- Node.js as executable for CSS preprocessor
- Drupal 7 with Bootstrap child theme

**Folder structure**

```
child_theme
  bootstrap
  css
  less
     mixins
```

How the imports occur:

**styles.less**

```
 // Bootstrap library.
  @import 'bootstrap.less';
  @import 'mixins.less';

@import 'doc-that-calls-mixin-function.less';
```

**mixins.less** //In charge of importing all files inside folder mixins

```
// Mixins
// Utilities
@import "mixins/animation.less";
```

**mixins/animation.less**

```
.RoundBorders (@radius) {
    border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
     -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
}
```

**doc-that-calls-mixin-function.less**

```
.rounded {
     .RoundBorders(4px);
}
```

With the layout above, whenever I hit save, it just spits this error out:

***NameError: .RoundBorders is undefined***

I have made sure I save each file as "UTF-8" , since I read somewhere that could be the problem. I have no idea why it's not seeing the mixin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is because you set Netbeans to compile each less file on save. So when you hit save it tries to compile just `doc-that-calls-mixin-function.less` and the error is expected since no `mixins/animation.less` is imported there... You need to configure it to recompile only `styles.less` only (I have no idea how to do this though, sorry).

Comment: That is true, it compiles on save (each file) instead of just compiling styles.less  I´ll need to search how to configure Netbeans to just compile styles.less on save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason as to "why" this problem was happening came from  @seven-phases-max 's upvoted comment. Quoting from him:

> This is because you set Netbeans to compile each less file on save. So when you hit save it tries to compile just doc-that-calls-mixin-function.less and the error is expected since no mixins/animation.less is imported there

@seven-phases-max suggest the following:

> You need to configure it [Netbeans] to recompile only styles.less

Alright, I looked for sites that could help me configure Netbeans to only recompile main file when I change any other Less file. I found nothing, only bugs and people wanting exactly the same. So there are two solutions to this:

**Solution 1 (not the one I applied)**

First solution is obvious (no I don't mean give up on Netbeans); just add `@import file_of_mixin_you_need` on the Less file where you call the mixin. In my case:

**doc-that-calls-mixin-function.less**

```
@import 'mixins.less';

.rounded {
     .RoundBorders(4px);
}
```

If it were a small project with few files, I'd get over it and just do it this way. Should you do it this way for a big project, or medium sized one? My answer is "heck no". Why? Well, it's `@import boilerplate` all over the place. How are you going to keep track of that?

**Solution 2 (the one I am currently using)**

This solution can only be carried out if you have Node.js installed in your system. Installing for Windows is a breeze, just go to Node.js site, and download the windows installer. Once downloaded in your console you will have access to "npm" command, use it to install lessc: `npm install -g less` . Now you are ready.

Well, in Netbeans I completely removed the "compile on save" deal. I opened my command windows and navigated to my Netbeans project's path, all the way to where my less files are. I leave that command window open and carry along. The moment I have finished saving and doing whatever I need in Netbeans IDE, here  are the steps to follow:

1. Delete file ../css/style.css    (Otherwise it won´t get overwritten on less compile)
2. Go to your command window (remember that you must be in your less folder) and carry out this command:

   lessc style.less > ...\css\style.css
3. Done

If you have any errors, the command window will show them. I chose this solution cause it avoids the  `@import boilerplate` on all my files. Also, I now longer have to worry about .gitignore"ing" the files that Netbeans was compiling (for every less file I had, it generated a css file).

That's it. Hope it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the second solution from @Joy, you might as well install `npm install watch -g` and run windows commandline `watch "lessc {your path}\style.less > {your path}\style.css" {your path}\less`

As soon as you save a file in the less directory watch will execute the lessc command. After execution it will wait for the next change.